Getting error when trying to configure SNS with AWS Cognito
I am trying to create a Cognito User Pool and I want it to be able to publish to an sns topic to send SMS messages. My main problem is that when I am trying to bound the resources on the sns topic policy document I am getting this error

Error: creating Cognito User Pool (my-user-pool): InvalidSmsRoleAccessPolicyException: Role does not have permission to publish with SNS

I am not very familiar with AWS and Terraform though so I am providing my configuration in case I've missed anything else.
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "my_user_pool" {
    name = "my-user-pool"

    password_policy {
      minimum_length                   = 8
      require_lowercase                = true
      require_uppercase                = true
      require_numbers                  = true
      require_symbols                  = false
      temporary_password_validity_days = 7
  }

    admin_create_user_config {
      allow_admin_create_user_only = true
    }

    auto_verified_attributes = ["phone_number"]
    mfa_configuration        = "OPTIONAL"

    software_token_mfa_configuration {
      enabled = true
    }

    sms_configuration {
      external_id    = local.cognito_my_sms_role_ext_id
      sns_caller_arn = aws_iam_role.my_cognito_sms_sender.arn
    }

    lifecycle {
      prevent_destroy = true
    }
  }

  resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "my_cognito_client" {
    name                    = "my-cognito-client"
    user_pool_id            = aws_cognito_user_pool.my_user_pool.id
    generate_secret         = false
    explicit_auth_flows     = ["ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH", "ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH"]
    enable_token_revocation = true
  }

  resource "aws_sns_topic" "my_update" {
    name              = "my_update"
    kms_master_key_id = "alias/aws/sns"
    delivery_policy   = file("sns_delivery_policy.json")
  }

  data "aws_iam_role" "my_service" {
    name = "my-service-eks-assume"
  }

  resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "my_cognito_user_access_attachment" {
    policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.my_cognito_access_policy.arn
    role       = data.aws_iam_role.my_credentials_manager.name
  }

  resource "aws_iam_policy" "my_cognito_access_policy" {
    name        = "my-cognito-access-policy"
    description = "Custom IAM policy for restricting Cognito actions"
    policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_cognito_access_policy_document.json
  }

  data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_cognito_access_policy_document" {
    statement {
      actions = [
        "cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth",
        "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
        "cognito-idp:AdminUserGlobalSignOut",
        "cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser",
        "cognito-idp:AdminSetUserPassword",
        "cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes",
        "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
        "cognito-idp:AdminGetUser",
        "cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser",
        "cognito-idp:AdminEnableUser",
        "cognito-idp:AdminDeleteUser",
        "cognito-idp:ListUsers",
        "cognito-idp:AdminSetUserMFAPreference",
      ]

      resources = ["arn:aws:cognito-idp:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:userpool/${aws_cognito_user_pool.my_user_pool.id}"]
    }
  }

  data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_cognito_assume_role_policy" {
    statement {
      actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

      principals {
        type        = "Service"
        identifiers = ["cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"]
      }
    }
  }

  resource "aws_iam_role" "my_cognito_sms_sender" {
    name               = "my-cognito-sms-sender"
    description        = "Permissions to send SMS messages"
    assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_cognito_assume_role_policy.json
  }

  resource "aws_iam_policy" "my_sns_publish_policy" {
    name   = "my-cognito-sns-publish-policy"
    policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_update_sns_topic_policy.json
    tags   = local.tags
  }

  resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "my_cognito_sns_publish_policy" {
    role       = aws_iam_role.my_cognito_sms_sender.name
    policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.my_sns_publish_policy.arn
  }

  data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_update_sns_topic_policy" {
    statement {
      actions   = ["sns:Publish"]
      resources = [aws_sns_topic.my_update.arn]

      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = [aws_cognito_user_pool.my_user_pool.arn]
      }
    }
}

If I do this instead:
ata "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_update_sns_topic_policy" {
    statement {
      actions   = ["sns:Publish"]
      resources = ["*"]

      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = [aws_cognito_user_pool.my_user_pool.arn]
      }
  }

I don't get an error but it is required not to use "*" and be more restrictive.
I have tried multiple configurations the last couple of days, but it seems that it only work using an asterisk in resources.
